# Fastest Way to recognise emoji in the unicode string with Python

Tags: python, unicode

Hy volk,

is there any fastest ways to recognize if given char is emoji?

Till this moment i found the following solution:

```
import emoji
character in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI
```

But it seems to be a not the best one, because to check if given char is in the dict, because you need to compute hash function and make lookup. What I mention, maybe it it possible just to check, if emoji Code point is inside of some range of Unicode code points, which are emojis. Any ideas, how to implement it?

Thx u in advance!

Comment: You could use the `caching python library` to cache results if the emoji has already been searched. This will speed your code up when there are many duplicates.

Comment: thx u. good idea, but this is actually an dict with uniq emojis. so, there r no duplicates)

Comment: Do you realise that ``dict`` and ``set`` containment tests are very fast?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yeap, and **dict** seems a little bit faster as **set** But, thx u for making me attention on it!=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is faster lookups in a list and you don't have any duplicates, you can try replacing `list()` with a `set()` instead.

> Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993659/7570485

**Update:**

As far as I know, you can't get any faster lookups than a `dict()`. Average time complexity for dict lookup is `O(1)`. You could try `intern()` in `sys` module to gain a small performance boost.

> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40694623/7570485

Comment: thx u=)) emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI is already an dict, and thats why already has this hash-tables magic... But your right, if it would be an list, than it could help!=)

Comment: I assumed you had a list as you have mentioned it as checking a `char` in a `list`. Please change it to `dict` to avoid further confusion.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered :)

Comment: done! One question more, do u know, if there any possibility to intern() also unicode string in python 2.7?

Comment: I believe `intern()` is built-in function in Python 2.7. In Python 3, it has been moved inside `sys.intern()`. If you are looking for providing compatibility for both, you can `try` importing `from sys import intern` on `except` pass and just use `intern` throughout the code.

Comment: yeap, but unfortunately, if i try to intern() an unicode object in python2.7, than i get this error: **TypeError: intern() argument 1 must be string, not unicode.**

Comment: Yeah, a lot of weird things happen in Python 2.7 when using Unicode. You can try to encode it to another format like utf-8, if it suits you. Or better yet stick to Python 3 :)

Comment: heh) u right. probably it will be my next step, to upgrade python=) Because the last python version 3.7 seems to be faster as python 2.7!