# Creating a dict of empty sets through a loop, then filling those sets using another loop - more efficient method? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, set

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63071541/8565438), I am creating a `dict` of empty `set`s by iterating through a list. Then I iterate through the same list & filling those sets. An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

---

```
# imports we need
import time
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
```

---

### What I am doing

An example list of letters. Note that *at least one* letter [will appear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) more than once.

```
letters=[np.random.choice([letter for letter in string.ascii_lowercase]) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Result:

> ['w', 'n', 'k', 'o', 'm', 'r', ...

Creating a `dict` with letters as keys, empty sets as values:

```
letterdict={letter:set() for letter in letters}
```

Iterating through the `letters` list again, each entry in the list with the corresponding letter will be a set where the indices of that letter appears in the `letters` list:

```
for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
    letterdict[letter].add(index)
```

`letterdict` will look like:

> {'w': {0, 12, 62, 67, 69, ...

---

### How long it was

This process took:

```
start = time.time()
letterdict={letter:set() for letter in letters}
for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
    letterdict[letter].add(index)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

`0.000538...` sec.

---

### The question

**Is there a way to make the creation of `letterdict` quicker?** Afterall, I am iterating through `letters` twice.

My thoughts: If I could make it in one loop, when it encounters a letter for the first time, I could create a `set`, and put the index of the letter in it. When encountering the letter for the second time, it could not reset the `set`, just add the index. However, *checking that a letter is already encountered or not* seems tedious (ie slow).

In the MRE, assume, that we do not know what all the letters are, so replacing the first loop by `{letter:set() for letter in string.ascii_lowercase}` is not really useful.

Comment: 0.000538... sec isn't quite fast enough?

Comment: It's just an example, I am using this with a real-world problem, where it takes much longer...

Comment: There is already a bit of an improvement if you do `letterdict = {letter:set() for letter in set(letters)}` (getting about 20-25% improvement by doing this when otherwise using your code but with 100000 in place of 1000).

Comment: Mind you, you could probably get rid of that first bit entirely by using a `defaultdict(set)`. Going to give that a test....  and the answer is that it maybe it improves it a little bit more but not dramatically beyond the improvement already mentioned (that is with `from collections import defaultdict` and `letterdict = defaultdict(set)`)

Comment: @alaniwi, Thanks! That indeed seems to make it faster, good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a `collections.defaultdict`.

This will create the empty set on lookup if the key is not already present:

```
from collections import defaultdict

letterdict = defaultdict(set)
for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
     letterdict[letter].add(index)
```

This way you don't have to initialize the dictionary with empty sets.

---

You could instead just use the `.setdefault()` method on a normal dict.

```
letterdict = {}
for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
     letterdict.setdefault(letter, set()).add(index)
```

This has the overhead of creating a new set object each time whether it's needed or not, but the builtin `set()` types seem to construct pretty quickly. It wasn't any slower on the small samples I used to time it. CPython might pool these somehow when they get deleted quickly, like it does for tuples.

Comment: Tested this, this is indeed faster than my method. Another improvement seem possible by using `enumerate(set(letters))`, as suggested by @alaniwi in the comments below OP...

Comment: @zabop wouldn't that change the answer though? You'd get different indexes than before.

Comment: @zabop For the record, I wasn't suggesting `enumerate(set(letters))`, but only using `set(letters)` where constructing the initial dictionary of empty sets (before I got the same idea as you about defaultdicts, which then made that bit redundant).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think there is no significant gain in time with this method, but you can do the same job with one loop, by using a try except block.

```
start = time.time()
for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
    try:
        letterdict[letter].add(index)
    except:
        letterdict[letter] = {index}
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Basically, we create a set while looping though the list, therefore no need for another loop.

My time, first is your method, second is mine:

> 0.0009996 #Your method
> 0.0009992 #My method

As I said, no significant gain, but according to several runs, it slightly faster.